# vnd.youtube:videoid not playing in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I used below code to play one video from youtube but its not working.

It showing Web page not available, But its available for that video id. Whats wrong with this code. Please help me.

```
setContentView(R.layout.youtube1);
        web=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.video1);


         web. getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled (true);
         web. getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically (false);
         web. getSettings().setPluginsEnabled (true);
         web. getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows (false);
         web. getSettings().setSupportZoom (false);
         web. setVerticalScrollBarEnabled (false);
         web. setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled (false);


         web. loadUrl ("vnd.youtube:3MWr19Dp2OU");

         web. setWebViewClient (new WebViewClient () {
             @ Override public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
             if (url.startsWith("vnd.youtube")){

             startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));

             return true;
             }
             else
             {
             return false;
             }
             }
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

An URI of the form `vnd.youtube:<video_id>` can be used with an `Intent` in order to start the YouTube application (if available on the device) and make it load the video identified by `<video_id>` (such as yours `3MWr19Dp2OU`). But if you rely on a `WebView`, you need to use the canonical URL (e.g. `http://www.youtube.com/v/3MWr19Dp2OU`) in order for the `WebView` to be able to load the video.

However, as you may find out sooner than later, playing YouTube videos in a `WebView` is not quite reliable. A possibly more viable solution is to exploit `VideoView` instead.